# Android WebView pauses javascript,then keeps executing it when tapped

Tags: java, android

I have a WebView in my app with javascript enabled:

```
textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser_main);

//Tried with those settings,nothing changed
/*webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);*/

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "interface");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.interface.receiveRaw(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");
    }
});
```

The URL I load returns just some text that's being updated by javascript with `setTimeout();`. However, after some lines of text WebView stops rendering the page. If I tap the screen the full page with the full text is shown.

For example, if the output of the page is

```
"Hello\nStack\nOverflow\nHow\nAre\nYou?"
```

I've got this when I start the app:

```
Hello
Stack
```

If I tap on the screen, the full text gets shown:

```
Hello
Stack
Overflow
How
Are
You?
```

The problem is that i need the full output when the app starts.

Is there any setting i can change?

May WebChromeClient solve the problem?